# Get disconnected from hostapd AP after association

Tags: networking, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect to a `hostapd` AP. The AP is a router (TP-LINK TALON AD7200) that is flashed to run OpenWrt firmware. When I run the command `hostapd hostapd_wlan2.conf` the output is:

```
root@TALON:/etc# hostapd hostapd_wlan2.conf
Configuration file: hostapd_wlan2.conf
Using interface wlan2 with hwaddr b0:4e:26:11:8f:f0 and ssid "TALON_AD7200"
wlan2: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan2: AP-ENABLED 
wlan2: STA 04:ce:14:07:47:d6 IEEE 802.11: associated
wlan2: AP-STA-CONNECTED 04:ce:14:07:47:d6
wlan2: STA 04:ce:14:07:47:d6 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
wlan2: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 04:ce:14:07:47:d6
```

It disconnects after it tries to connect. I am trying to connect a laptop that runs Ubuntu 16.04 to the router. 
The content of the config file is:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd_wlan2
interface=wlan2
driver=nl80211
ssid=TALON_AD7200
channel=2
hw_mode=ad
```

The AP does not have any encryptions.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The default distribution of ubuntu 16.04 doesn't implement the needed driver to communicate with dot11ad equipment.

You are left with two choices:

1. Use an OS distribution that, by default, implements the wil6200 driver (e.g. Acer TravelMate)
2. use another TALON AD7200 client

In case you choose option number 2, on the recent patched openwrt distribution that SEEMOO labs published, you do not need to configure your talon as an AP. 
Check the 60GHz leds, if they are flashing in both pieces of equipment, it means that you can establish a link. If not, reboot then again and again until you get it working.

I'm working with this hardware, feel free to contact me.